# Часть сказуемого, или — обстоятельство?

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, наречия, обстоятельство

В каких случаях наречие является частью составного именного сказуемого, а в каких — обстоятельством?

Например, здесь: «*Семен оглянулся вокруг*».

Не могу понять, чем оно является.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Семен оглянулся вокруг. Здесь наречие является обстоятельством, но наречие может входить в составное именное сказуемое.

Составное именное сказуемое включает связку и именную часть, которая выражается различными частями речи, в том числе наречием.

Существует три вида связок: знаменательная БЫТЬ (она обычно опускается), полузнаменательная ЯВЛЯТЬСЯ, КАЗАТЬСЯ, ВЫГЛЯДЕТЬ И ДР. (он показался мне усталым),  и знаменательная - глаголы со значением движения или состояния (он пришел усталый, он спал одетый, линия получилась неровной). В приведенном примере глагол "оглянулся" не является связкой для наречия, так как он не имеет значение движения или положения.

Вообще говоря, знаменательная связка - вопрос сложный, так как это не полноценное служебное слово, а глагол с определенным предикативным признаком, такие варианты могут рассматриваться как ДУПЛЕКСИВЫ (двойные связи), когда предикативное определение согласуется и с подлежащим, и сказуемым.

Примеры составного именного сказуемого с  НАРЕЧИЕМ и нулевой связкой: Он с ними заодно. Сосед навеселе. Друзья рядом. Сестра замужем. Теперь всё будет по-новому.

Пример с полузнаменательной связкой и наречием: Он выглядит впечатляюще.

А вот примеров со знаменательной связкой и наречием, кажется, и нет.

Comment: ???

Vera: "Примеры составного именного сказуемого с НАРЕЧИЕМ и нулевой связкой:  
...Теперь всё будет по-новому". 

===

В этом примере НЕ НУЛЕВАЯ СВЯЗКА.

Comment: Спасибо, Слава, невнимательно списала примеры. Связка ненулевая.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно поставить вопрос и решить, какой это член предложения.

"Семен (что сделал?) оглянулся (как?) вокруг"  (Где?) Вокруг ни души. - обстоятельство.

"Вокруг" может быть или наречием-обстоятельством или предлогом: Бегал (где?) вокруг дома. - предлог с существительным - обстоят.

Она весело побежала. Побежала (как?) весело - наречие, в предложении явл. обстоятельством.

Мне весело. Мне было весело. Мне (каково?) весело. - категория состояния, сост. именное сказуемое безличного предложения.